# Magento event observer not working on some machines

Tags: php, events, magento, controller, mage

I cannot seem to figure out why my event observer works from my machine (and another coworkers) but not from other machines in the office.

For example, I have an observer that listens for the event:

```
controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_process_reindexProcess
```

My code detects the event and runs some code.  When I run the re-index process, my code executes.  When certain other machines here in the office run the re-index, either the event is not fired, or my observer isn't detecting it.

Why would the computer or the user clicking on the re-index button in the admin panel change anything for how events are fired or observed?

I have researched this problem as best I could and found this post.

[Events not firing/or observer not working in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924751/events-not-firing-or-observer-not-working-in-magento)

But that seemed to pertain to different installations.  In my problem, it works on a given installation on certain computers and not from others so I felt that this article was not directly relevant.

This problem is driving me crazy.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a whole lot of voodoo you could try, but what you'll end up having to in the end is start here

```
#File: app/Mage.php

public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    #$result = self::registry('events')->dispatch($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

and debug/log the execution of your event to determine why it isn't firing in certain situations.

**Specific Answer From Comments**

> Thanks! I was able to see that re-indexing from the check marks calls a different event than simply clicking on the re-index process text. A painfully long error to debug but a simple solution. Thanks again! –

Comment: Yes good poing to put Mage::log($name); and simply compare output of 2 computers.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to see that re-indexing from the check marks calls a different event than simply clicking on the re-index process text.  A painfully long error to debug but a simple solution.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the same file state on both computer?
Maybe you forget to transfer/check-in the MyFirm_MyModule.xml and your module is not active?

Are the computers using different operating systems? If you are on Windows and your colleagues are on Linux it might be a problem with uppercase/lowercase of module names.