# Event Observer is not working in multiple store

Tags: php, magento

I have my own custom module observer to listen customer_login event. I can run the observer method in main website store. When I moved to other store the customer_login event is not triggered while the customer logged in. It works perfectly in main store. I could'nt find out the solution . I have followed [Magento event observer not working on some machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409085/magento-event-observer-not-working-on-some-machines) and [Events not firing/or observer not working in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924751/events-not-firing-or-observer-not-working-in-magento).

Thanks in advance.

My config is

```
   `<events>
        <customer_login>
            <observers>
               <mymodule>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>Mypackage_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
                  <method>runAfterLogin</method> 
               </mymodule> 
            </observers>
        </customer_login>
    </events>`
```

Comment: Please include your config.xml part, which you have for observer registration.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the stpes mentioned in the link below, it works awesome :)

http://codemagento.com/2011/04/observers-and-dispatching-events/